# Change fontcolor of only one textblock among multiple

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

i have multiple textblock and i need to change the font color of the textblock based on date. Just as in calendar where today will be of different color than the other day. how can i code it? help. thanks in advance.

```XAML
<TextBlock
  x:Name="day1"
  Style="{StaticResource styleForTextbox}"
  Text="1" />
.......
 <TextBlock
  x:Name="day50"
  Style="{StaticResource styleForTextbox}"
  Text="50" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Foreground to a Converter that takes in your text input.

LINK: [MSDN Converter Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

```XAML
<TextBlock Name="day" Foreground="{Binding Path=DayBinding, Converter={StaticResource DateToColorConverter}}"/>
```

Remember in your Converter to return a `Brush` not a Color.